# Pandas not summing values in two numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | DIV0 |
| 3 | DIV0 |
| 5 | DIV0 |
| DIV0 | 3 |

I want to add a 3rd column 'C' which would be the sum of values in A & B:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | DIV0 | 2 |
| 3 | DIV0 | 3 |
| 5 | DIV0 | 5 |
| DIV0 | 3 | 3 |

In my current code, the `DIV0` values are removed and `A` and `B` are summed by the following lines:

```
df["A"] = pd.to_numeric(df["A"],errors="coerce")
df["B"] = pd.to_numeric(df["B"],errors="coerce")
df["C"] = df["A"] + df["B"]
```

However this gives me an empty `C` column - I've tried researching numeric columns but can't understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the default `fill_value` of [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) is `NaN` and when you perform an arithmetic operation (*like `+`*) involving `NaN`, the result is also `NaN`. So you need to set the fill value to `0`.

```
s1 = pd.to_numeric(df["A"], errors="coerce")
s2 = pd.to_numeric(df["B"], errors="coerce")
​
df["C"] = s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)
```

Another variant (*if you have a lot of columns*) with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) :

```
df["C"] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").sum(axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      A     B    C
0     2  DIV0  2.0
1     3  DIV0  3.0
2     5  DIV0  5.0
3  DIV0     3  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
df['sum'] = (df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).sum(axis=1, min_count=1))
```

Output:

[image]